# Logical Standby in NOARCHIVELOG mode (Oracle 12C database)

Tags: oracle

If there is any possibility to turn off NOARCHIVELOG mode in oracle Logical Standby database, because our environment that logical standby database use only for the report generating purpose and our lot of reports are running with global temporary table and I have monitoring when we using global temporary table, the archive generation is very high. Please any one have solution for this?

Also in our production database (12C) already have physical standby and NOARCHIVELOG mode is turning on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found answer referring from below article.

https://databaseinternalmechanism.com/oracle-12c-miscellaneous/12c-new-features-global-temporary-table-undo/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog

In Oracle 12c has new feature for controlled redo in global temporary tables is by a new init.ora parameter: temp_undo_enabled.

alter session set temp_undo_enabled = false;